# proc macro that operates on every `fn` in crate?

Tags: rust

I'd like to apply a `#[tracing::instrument]` attribute to every function definition in my crate. Is this possible? My approach would be to write a proc macro that's applied to the root module, which visits every fn in the crate (with `syn`) and injects the instrument attribute, but it seems that this is not very well supported

```
error[E0658]: inner macro attributes are unstable
...
  = note: see issue #54726 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54726> for more information
  = help: add `#![feature(custom_inner_attributes)]` to the crate attributes to enable
```

is there a better way to accomplish this?

and

```
error[E0658]: non-inline modules in proc macro input are unstable
...
   = note: see issue #54727 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54727> for more information
   = help: add `#![feature(proc_macro_hygiene)]` to the crate attributes to enable
```

Answer (score 0):

On nightly, just use the features, elsewhere you can wrap all your code in a function like macro:

```rust
// your sub modules
your_macro_crate::add_tracing!{
    // the regular contents of your file without the modules
}
```

But that's a workaround rather than a full solution.

Or maybe you prefer to use a `build.rs` script to literally put the `#[tracing::instrument]` attributes in the code.